# How to redirect wordpress website IP address to a home page

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, seo

i don't know how to redirect my website IP address to home page for example

123.255.25.3 to http://www.example.com my website code language is wordpress if anybody know let me explain how to resolve this probelm

Answer (score 0):

Add to document root .htaccess file with config

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,QSA]
```